# Написать и добавить регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить проверку на ввод почты в данном коде. Как именно нужно дописать код, чтобы была проверка на введенные данные?

`` string pattern = @"^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" + @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,17}))$"; ``

```
    private void BTN_SignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TXT_UserRole.Text != "" && TXT_Name.Text != "" && TXT_DOB.Text != "" && TXT_MobileNO.Text != "" && TXT_Email.Text != "" && TXT_Username.Text != "" && TXT_Password.Text != "")
        {
            String role = TXT_UserRole.Text;
            String name_ = TXT_Name.Text;
            String DOB = TXT_DOB.Text;
            Int64 mobile = Int64.Parse(TXT_MobileNO.Text);
            String email = TXT_Email.Text;
            String username = TXT_Username.Text;
            String password = TXT_Password.Text;
            DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Now;
            string date = thisDay.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");

            try
            {
                query = "insert into users (userRole, name_, dob, mobile, email, username, pass, dataReg) values ('" + role + "', '" + name_ + "', '" + DOB + "', '" + mobile + "', '" + email + "', '" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + date + "')";
                fn.setData(query, "Sign Up successfull.");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username Already exist" + e, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            TXT_Username_TextChanged(this, null);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Заполните все поля!", "Информация", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string YourEmail; // почта которую нужно проверить
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[-\w.]+@([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"); // само регулярное выражение
if (rgx.IsMatch(YourEmail)) {
    // тут код в случае соответствия 
 }
```

Вот не только рабочий способ, но и хорошее регулярное выражение которое не пропустит почты типа: somemail@gmail и тому подобных. Надеюсь помог вам. Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы действительно мне очень помогли) Всего наилучшего!